# Gelfand-Naimark theorem and compactifications

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactification, gelfand-representation

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and let $C(X)$ denote the set of all continuous and bounded functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$. It is a well-known fact that $C(X)$ forms a unital and abelian $C^*$-algebra (where the addition, multiplication, and scalar multiplication are defined pointwise, $C(X)$ is endowed with the sup norm, and the $*$ operation is conjugation)

Gelfand-Naimark theorem says the following: any unital and abelian $C^*$-algebra is isomorphic to $C(\mathbf{X}),$ where $\mathbf{X}$ is some compact and Hausdorff space, and $C(X)$ denotes the set of all continuous and bounded functions from $\mathbf{X}$ to $\mathbb{C}.$

Consequently, for any Hausdorff space $X,$ there exists a compact and Hausdorff space $\mathbf{X}$ such that $C(X)$ is isomorphic to $C(\mathbf{X}).$

**Question**: Is $\mathbf{X}$ a compactification of $X$?

By a compactification I mean the following: $\mathbf{X}$ is a compactification of $X$ if and only if $X$ embeds as an open and dense subspace in $\mathbf{X}$ (I know that the requirement that $X$ is open in $\mathbf{X}$ is usually not a part of the definition of a compactification, but I would like to include it)

**Bonus question 1:** What conditions do $C(X)$ or $X$ need to satisfy to make sure that $\mathbf{X}$ is a compactification of $X?$

**Bonus question 2:** If $C_b(X)$ denote the set of all bounded (and not necessarily continuous) functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{C},$ then $C_b(X)$ is a unital and abelian $C^*$ algebra. Is $\mathbf{X}$ from the Gelfand-Naimark theorem a compactification of $X?$ Why or why not?

As always, any help will be appreciated and rewarded.

Thank you.

Comment: $X$ has to be locally compact to have a compactification in your sense.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma And why is that?

Comment: because an open subset of a compact Hausdorff space is locally compact and completely regular.

Comment: I understand. Is this a sufficient condition or just necessary?

Comment: Both necessary and sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general (for any topological space $X$ at all), $\mathbf{X}$ is the *Stone-Cech compactification* of $X$.  That is, there is a canonical continuous map $i:X\to\mathbf{X}$ such that for every compact Hausdorff space $K$ and every continuous map $f:X\to K$, there is a unique continuous map $g:\mathbf{X}\to K$ such that $gi=f$.  (Explicitly, $\mathbf{X}$ is the space of $*$-homomorphisms $C(X)\to\mathbb{C}$, and $i:X\to\mathbf{X}$ takes any $x\in X$ to the homomorphism given by evaluation at $x$.)

Now, the Stone-Cech compactification is not always a compactification in your sense.  Specifically, it is a compactification (embedding with dense open image) iff $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.  This condition is obviously necessary, since any open subspace of a compact Hausdorff space is locally compact Hausdorff.  Conversely, the image of $i$ is always dense, and $i$ is an embedding iff $X$ is completely regular.  In particular, if $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff then $i$ is a embedding with dense image and its image is therefore open since any dense locally compact subspace of a compact Hausdorff space is open.

As for what you call $C_b(X)$, it is just $C(X_d)$ where $X_d$ is $X$ with the discrete topology.  So, the $\mathbf{X}$ you obtain from this is just the Stone-Cech compactification of $X_d$.  This will never be a compactification of $X$ in a canonical way unless $X$ is discrete so that $X=X_d$ (in particular, the canonical map $i:X\to\mathbf{X}$ is not continuous with respect to any topology on $X$ besides the discrete topology, since it is an embedding with respect to the discrete topology).

(Incidentally, what you call $C(X)$ is what is more commonly called $C_b(X)$.  Typically $C(X)$ refers to the algebra of all (not necessarily bounded) continuous functions on $X$.)

Comment: Eric, I am sorry for using a non-standard notation. Also, this is a second question of mine that you answered with a crystal clear and thorough explanation. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't mind, I would like to ask you one more question: what happens if we restrict what I called $C(X)$ to some smaller sub-algebra? For example, what if  $C'(X)$ is a collection of bounded and continuous functions from a metric space $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that each for all $\epsilon>0,$ and all $r>0$ there exists a compact set $K$ in $X \times X$ such that outside of that compact set $K$ we have
 $$d(x,y)< \epsilon \implies d(f(x),f(y))<R.$$
$C(X)$ is still a unital and abelian $C^*$-algebra (under the usual operations). Is $\mathbf{X}$ still a compactification of $X?$

Comment: If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $A$ is a unital $C^*$-subalgebra of $C_b(X)$ (what you called $C(X)$), then $A$ corresponds to a compactification of $X$ iff $A$ contains all functions with compact support (and every compactification can be obtained in this way).  In particular, this is true of your $C'(X)$, so it gives a compactification of $X$ (as long as $X$ is locally compact).

Comment: Great! "A corresponds to a compactification of X iff A contains all functions with compact support" - why is that? I'm sorry for so many questions!

Comment: Every function with compact support extends continuously to every compactification, by just making it $0$ at all the new points.  So it is necessary for $A$ to contain all functions with compact support.  Conversely, functions with compact support generate the topology on $X$ (that is, the topology on $X$ is the coarsest topology making them all continuous).  So, if they all extend continuously to $\mathbf{X}$, then the image of $X$ in $\mathbf{X}$ must have the same topology, so it's an embedding.

Comment: I am not exactly sure that I understand your last comment. If $A$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $C(X)$ (I am using your notation/standard notation), then there exists $\mathbf{X}$ such that $A$ is isomorphic to $C(\mathbf{X}).$ However, $\mathbf{X}$ is no longer the Stone-Cech compactification of $X.$ Thus, I am not completely sure why continuous extensions of functions with compact support matter. In other words, I don't know the following: 1)  If $\mathbf{X}$ happens to be a compactification of $X,$ then why is it necessary that $A$ contains all the functions with compact support?

Comment: Maybe my confusion comes from not knowing how the isomorphism really looks like. If $f$ belongs to $A$, then does $f$ correspond to its extension in $C_b(\mathbf{X})$? Or is it correspondence only true in case of $C_b(X)?$

Comment: Let $\beta X$ denote the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$ and let $i:X\to\beta X$ be the canonical inclusion map.  The inclusion homorphism $A\to C_b(X)$ can be thought of as a homomorphism $C(\mathbf{X})\to C(\beta X)$, which is given by composition with some continuous map $f:\beta X\to\mathbf{X}$ (which is surjective because the inclusion homomorphism is injective).  So, composing $f$ and $i$, we have a map $fi:X\to\mathbf{X}$, and the inclusion homomorphism $C(\mathbf{X})\cong A\to C_b(X)$ is given by composition with $fi$.

Comment: This means that the elements of $A$ are exactly the continuous functions on $X$ which can be obtained by composing a continuous function on $\mathbf{X}$ with $fi$.  In other words, if you think of $fi$ as an inclusion of $X$ into $\mathbf{X}$, they are exactly the continuous functions on $X$ which extend continuously to $\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: Thank you for all your time and answers! One more thing seems unclear to me, though. "Functions with compact support generate the topology on X" - I understand that functions with constant support generate some topology on $X.$ However, how do I know that that topology is not "coarser" than the original topology on $X?$

Comment: That follows from the fact that $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, and involves Urysohn's lemma.